# Specify an association table in Code First

Tags: entity-framework

Consider the scenario where an entity called List can hold many User.

```
public class List{
  public int Id{get;set;}

  public string Name{get;set;}

  public virtual List<User>Users{get;set;

}

public class User{
  public int Id{get;set;}

  public string Name{get;set;}

  public virtual List<List>List{get;set;

}
```

I have an association table called ListUserAssociation in my db and that contains multiple records.

The Table has 2 columns ListId and UserId

How do I specify this association in EF code First?

P.S . I cannot drop and recreate the table.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what you are trying to do? When you do user.List or list.Users, EF will use the lookup table to fulfill this data get - it doesn't need to be specified as part of your code-first models as EF maps from relational to object-oriented for you

Answer (score 0):

Since you have collections defined on both sides, you can define the relationship from either side:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<List>().HasMany(e => e.Users).WithMany(e => e.List).Map(ca => ca.MapLeftKey(new string[] {"ListId"}).MapRightKey(new string[] {"UserId"}).ToTable("ListUserAssociation");
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.List).WithMany(e => e.Users).Map(ca => ca.MapLeftKey(new string[] {"UserId"}).MapRightKey(new string[] {"ListId"}).ToTable("ListUserAssociation");
```

I believe you only need one line or the other in order to define the relationship.  Even though it is redundant, I prefer to include both lines so that I see the relationship defined from either entity (I place all of the mapping code in separate classes for each entity).